# 3D mapping using only datasets and no hardware

Tags: 3d-reconstruction

I am planning a project which compares the different techniques of 3D mapping of a setup. I understand that there are many algorithms to accomplish the same, but due to a non-existent hardware budget, I have to compare 3D techniques/algorithms that can be accomplished with the algorithm and datasets only. I have done a fair share of research that is still ongoing, but I was looking for assistance by people who may already have knowledge of this and can help me narrow down what I'm searching.
In summary, I am looking for 3D mapping techniques/algorithms that can be accomplished using only software and datasets in order to compare them on various performance and application parameters. Since I have to compare performance, all techniques should be applied on the same dataset.
I would appreciate any information, research papers, links, otherwise that could direct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need no hardware for this :)

Check out [OpenSLAM](https://www.openslam.org/) website, you'll find plenty of options for slam algorithms and dataset. A quick Google search gives you things such as the [KITTI Dataset](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_odometry.php).

I particularly like [this webpage](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~stachnis/datasets.html) to find datasets.

Most of those can be used with ROS so I would advise you to implement your comparison method in ROS. Then testing different slam algorithm and/or datasets is mainly a matter of (almost) plug and play.

Comment: Thank you @Malcom. The information you provided was very helpful in creating my proposal. However, as I dive into actually implementing the algorithms on ROS, I am only concerned about how to match the algorithm to the dataset. I'm hoping I get the hang of it as I go on.

Comment: If that answer answered your question, don't forget to accept it :)